# Mutating method sent to immutable object error when removing object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I want to remove object from array but I am getting this error. I found relative questions but not able to get.
please help me.
my code is

```
NSArray *tripsArray= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSMutableArray *myTripsArray = [tripsArray mutableCopy];
for (NSDictionary *dict in myTripsArray){
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"state"] isEqualToString:@"undeployed"]){
        int index = [myTripsArray indexOfObject:dict];
        [myTripsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you're receiving? Not `Collection was mutated while being enumerated.`?

Comment: yes @JamesP I am getting same error

Comment: I was just a bit confused as you posted a different error in your question, (which would be caused by another reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the array which you are iterating, you are removing an object from the same array.

Change this line:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in myTripsArray)
```

To this:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in [myTripsArray copy])
```

Here I used the copy of the array to iterate and used the original one to mutate.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
NSArray *tripsArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSMutableArray *myTripsArray = [tripsArray mutableCopy];
for (NSDictionary *dict in [myTripsArray copy]){
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"state"] isEqualToString:@"undeployed"]){
        int index = [myTripsArray indexOfObject:dict];
        [myTripsArray removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}

// And now myTripsArray will be changed
```

Answer (score 1):

You got the error because you tried to change an array in enumerating time. You should make copy of this array and use one array for enumerating and second for removing. Or you can add all items for removing (which you will find in cicle) in second array and then just remove them by call `removeObject:`.

Don't store indexes cause after first remove second index can be wrong (if second object has higher index than first).